# Sharepoint script for long path ways and some file types

Tags: powershell, script

I have heard that there is a script that we can run on the files and folders before migration and it helps us to not the have errors like "long path way" etc.

This script as i know run in powershell .

Would you know that please?

Thank you in advance for the replies

Answer (score 0):

look at [this topic](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/57318fa5-20e3-49d8-ae74-27c8355c4412/powershell-to-find-url-lengths-greater-than-260-characters?forum=sharepointdevelopment) and try use the script in the Answer.